# Delete an object from Json File using sed command and display changes within the same file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I am having a json file in which a json object need to be deleted. Is there any way to delete it by sed command only. My sample file is given below:

```
define({
    name: 'ABC',
    defaultApp: 'abc',
    plugin: 'plugin',
    loadOverride: 'load.json',
    logger: {
        url: '/rest/service/log',
        sendFrequency: 5000,
        autoLog: false
    },
});
```

In this file i want to remove logger object from the file by sed command.

Expected output:

```
define({
    name: 'ABC',
    defaultApp: 'abc',
    plugin: 'plugin',
    loadOverride: 'load.json',
});
```

I tried using this command but it's not working. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

```
sed -i '/\"logger\"/,/}/ d; /^$/d' ./config1.js
```

Thanks.

Comment: sed is really not the right tool for parsing JSON data, but this isn't JSON data, it's, what, a javascript snippet. Nevertheless, this would work on this input: `sed '/logger/,/}/d'`

Comment: Are indentations constant?

Comment: @revo yes the indentations are constant....

Comment: @glennjackman The command worked fine and perfect.....Thanks for your response. For modifying the same file by removing the logger object I used: sed -i '/logger/,/}/d' ./config1.js. It works :)

Answer (score 0):

Your own `sed` script doesn't match the beginning address because you have double quotation marks around `logger` while there is no such pattern in input file. So pattern doesn't match. If indentations are fixed you could use this:

```
sed 's/^    logger/,/^    },/d;`
```